# Create a dictionary using PyEnchant Language Dictionarie

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pyenchant

I am trying to create a new dictionary from an english language dictionary that i have using PyEnchant.For example : the english word--> 'new'  to become--> 'new':1e1n1w (i am counting the letters alphabetically)
 My problem is that i do not know how to access the objects of the english language dictionary so i can make a repetition structure and create the ne dictionary or change this one.(I have two files that make the dictionary , one FFT and one txt.)

Comment: do you want to know how to convert "new" to "1e1n1w" ? is that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from a word and convert it to letter count / letter format, sorted alphabetically:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "new"

c = Counter(s)

print("".join(["{}{}".format(v,k) for k,v in sorted(c.items())]))
```

- count letters of the word using special `Counter` dictionary made for that purpose
- create the new "word" using list comprehension by iterating on counter keys & values (sorted), recreating the string using `str.join`

results in: `1e1n1w`

One-liner to create the list from input list (here: 2 items) using listcomps:

```
newlist = ["".join(["{}{}".format(v,k) for k,v in sorted(Counter(word).items())]) for word in ['new','hello']]
```

results in:

```
['1e1n1w', '1e1h2l1o']
```

Comment: Theres no need for the for loop, `c = Counter(s)` would do the work.